# Index of element of one array in another array avoiding list::utils

Tags: arrays, perl

> Aim: To match two array and find the index position of matched element.
>
> Tricky part: As per the example given below, the elements of each array are not exactly similar to each other but the comprise of some part and I want to match that.

Sample of how the arrays are:

```
array1=('adam west', 'daric dalon','tom helic','todd nick','riley remer'); 

array2=('adam west 12', 'daric dalon mr.','tom helic (fads)','todd nick (456)','riley remer','john steve','dim madz 12');
```

I have tried using `List::MoreUtils qw(first_index);` method but this method isn't giving what I want.

**The following I have tried:**

Try 1

```
for my $name (@Names) {
    $count;
    for $matchList (@org_name) {
        if ( index( $matchList, $name ) != -1 ) {
            push (@matched,$matchList);
            $count++;
            }#print $org_name[$count];
    }
} print "Those which are matched @matched\n";
```

Try 2

The next method I have copied from online but not very much useful.

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(first_index);
@indexes;

foreach my $place (@allNames) {
    push @indexes, first_index { $_ eq $place } @org_name;
}
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);
print Dumper \@indexes;
```

I know this is going to be a very easy thing which I am missing out. But please let me know what I can do.

Comment: "isn't turning out good", "this as well isn't helping". It might help us if you were a little clearer about what problems you had with the approaches you have tried. Your descriptions aren't very clear.

Comment: some sample data and expected output would be helpful in understanding what you want

Comment: @DaveCross I am sorry for the less information. Basically my you can imagine it as:
array1=('adam west', 'daric dalon','tom helic','todd nick','riley remer');
array2=('adam west 12', 'daric dalon mr.','tom helic (fads)','todd nick (456)','riley remer','john steve','dim madz 12');

Now you can see that the elements do not exactly match each other, but that is not the issue, my script matches it efficiently. The problem is when I am trying to find out the index of the element in bigger array, here array2.

Comment: @ysth
I am sorry for the inconvenience.
Sample:
array1=('adam west', 'daric dalon','tom helic','todd nick','riley remer');
array2=('adam west 12', 'daric dalon mr.','tom helic (fads)','todd nick (456)','riley remer','john steve','dim madz 12');

Expected output:
Index of the matched element in the bigger array, here array2.

Comment: @KrushnaSonar: For important clarifications like this, you shouldn't just dump the new information in a comment. Firstly, the formatting in comments is terrible and secondly, people might not read the comment. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45353287/edit) to add your new information.

Comment: And, really, the information about the elements of the two arrays not being identical is crucial information. You really should have put that in your question from the start.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need something like this:

```
use Data::Dumper

my @indexes = ();
#create hash of "first_index" elemets in @org_name
my %tmp = map { $org_name[$_] => $_ } reverse 0..$#org_name;

for my $t (@allNames) {
    if(exists($tmp{$t})) {
        push @indexes, $tmp{$t};
    }
}

print Dumper @indexes;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 if ( index( $matchList, $name ) != -1 ) {
```

You haven't explained what you mean by "match two arrays". I think you might be looking for elements that are in both arrays. But the line above isn't testing for equality of two strings, it is testing if `$name` appears as a substring of `$matchList`. Is that what you want?

If you want to test for equality, you should use this instead:

```
 if ($matchList eq $name) {
```

But the substring check should still work if your strings are equal. If they aren't matching, then it sounds like your arrays don't contain what you think they contain. Perhaps one array contains elements that still have newlines attached - or something like that.

If you're actually trying to find the elements that appear in both arrays, then (as it often the case) the [Perl FAQ](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq.html) will be useful. You're looking for the intersection of two sets and [perlfaq4](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html) contains this:

> **How do I compute the difference of two arrays? How do I compute the
>   intersection of two arrays?**
>
> Use a hash. Here's code to do both and
>   more. It assumes that each element is unique in a given array:
>
> ```
> my (@union, @intersection, @difference);
> my %count = ();
> foreach my $element (@array1, @array2) { $count{$element}++ }
> foreach my $element (keys %count) {
>     push @union, $element;
>     push @{ $count{$element} > 1 ? \@intersection : \@difference }, $element;
> }
> ```
>
> Note that this is the symmetric difference, that is, all elements in either A or in B but not in both. Think of it as an xor operation.

**Update:** Having seen what you want, most of what I said above is completely off-topic. Please try to be clearer when asking questions.

What you actually want is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my @arr1 = ('adam west', 'daric dalon', 'tom helic','todd nick', 'riley remer');
my @arr2 = ('adam west 12', 'daric dalon mr.','tom helic (fads)',
            'todd nick (456)', 'riley remer', 'john steve', 'dim madz 12');

# Match elements from array1 ...
for my $e1 (@arr1) {
  # ... against indexes in array2
  for my $i2 (0 .. $#arr2) {
    if ($arr2[$i2] =~ /^\Q$e1/) {
      say "$e1 -> $i2";
    }
  }
}
```

Or you can use `List::MoreUtils::firstidx` like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use List::MoreUtils 'firstidx';

use feature 'say';

my @arr1 = ('adam west', 'daric dalon', 'tom helic','todd nick', 'riley remer');
my @arr2 = ('adam west 12', 'daric dalon mr.','tom helic (fads)',
            'todd nick (456)', 'riley remer', 'john steve', 'dim madz 12');

# Match elements from array1 ...
for my $e1 (@arr1) {
  # ... against indexes in array2
  if ((my $i2 = firstidx { /^\Q$e1/ } @arr2) == -1) {
    say "$e1 not found in \@arr2";
  } else {
    say "$e1 -> $i2";
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP messed up the way he asked this question, no doubt. That said, I don't think you're using regexes in a safe way. If you want to check that one string starts with another, using `index()` would be safer, and `substr`+`eq` would be both safe and fast, albeit verbose. (Also, I'm still not sure this is what the OP meant. I interpreted his comments differently than you. But it doesn't matter--if he needs the right answer, he can write the right question. But the regex thing is significant--or if I'm wrong, could you let me know why?)

Comment: @piojo: You're right. The regex was perfectly safe with the sample data I was using, but I've added `\Q` to make it safe for all input. I don't like using `index()` as its interface (returning `-1` for no match) makes code over-complicated.

Comment: It looks like `\Q` and `\E` are parsed before variables are interpolated. Safer than I expected. That feature will be useful. Thanks for remarking on it!